# Saving Outlook email file with Matlab

Tags: html, email, matlab, outlook, office-interop

I'm trying to parse Outlook emails by saving them as HTML files to my local machine using MATLAB. I know that actxserver allows me to communicate between MATLAB and Outlook, but how do I save the actual email?

Thanks!

Comment: So you'd want to use matlab as a scripting language to export Outlook emails? That's like using a bulldozer to put a nail in the wall... Wouldn't you be better off using something that is made for this kind of tasks (like [powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox.aspx) for example)?

Comment: No, really, why in the world would you want to do that!?

Comment: All of my code exists in MATLAB, and I am pretty sure it's very easy - something like email.SaveAs('C:\Users\...\testEmail.html') - but that gives me a lot of garbled text, and then one line for the entire email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
outlook = actxserver('Outlook.Application');
mapi=outlook.GetNamespace('mapi')
INBOX=mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
firstemail=INBOX.Items.GetFirst
subject = firstemail.get('Subject');
body = firstemail.get('HTMLBody');
```

from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/167787

or download REDMAIL.m from the OFE:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33684-readmail

Comment: This is close! I want to be able to save it as HTML so I can parse the actual HTML tags.

Comment: @MarthFrake: that would be: `html = firstemail.get('HTMLBody')`, then save the returned string to a file

Answer (score 1):

Profit from MATLABs Java scripting capability using a library like [java-libpst](http://code.google.com/p/java-libpst/).